# Can I safely replace all net46 dependencies on nuget packages with net45?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

My project when I started it was .net 4.6, however then I wanted to add a reference to Interop.CERTENROLLLib.Unofficial and I couldnt, so I changed my project to .net 4.5 and then I could add that reference.

However all other references are in 46

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AngleSharp" version="0.9.9" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Interop.CERTENROLLLib.Unofficial" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net46" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="2.0.6" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.6.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph.Core" version="1.4.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Identity.Client" version="1.0.304142201-alpha" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel" version="6.1.7600.16394" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="3.19.5" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="5.2.1" targetFramework="net46" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.2.1" targetFramework="net46" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net46" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net46" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net46" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net46" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Online.CSOM" version="15.0.4859.1003" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM" version="16.1.7618.1200" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="SharePointPnP.IdentityModel.Extensions" version="1.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="SharePointPnPCoreOnline" version="2.26.1805.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="4.0.4.403061554" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net46" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net46" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net46" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net46" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net46" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

And in VS I get lots of warnings, what should I do? Should I downgrade manually or?

Comment: Why do you need that? You can easily add a COM reference and the assembly would be generated by Visual Studio. It is lazy to use a NuGet package when it is completely unnecessary. Also there is no need to downgrade to net45.

Comment: Perhaps you could create an identical project from scratch, except choosing net 4.5. Then copy the packages section from that project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I created the project from scartch to .net 4.5 and added references manually and then all warnings are gone.

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution when one finds themselves in this situation...

1. Set the project with runtime target conflicts to the runtime you want, i.e. NET45 or NET46.
2. Then with NuGet Package Management CLI invoke a reinstall of the packages.

`CLI:> Update-Package -proj MyProject -reinstall`

It not only fixes the `packages.config` but also the `.CSPROJ` dependencies and the `web.config` Assembly Redirects.